# How to debug Java code when it is out of sync?

Tags: java, eclipse

One of the problems I'm running into is that my jar files and my source files don't match.

I'd like to:

1. Be Notified when when source and binary don't match (I think Visual Studio can do something like this...)
2. Set break points not by line, but by function.  For example, set a break point at the entry of function foo().

I use eclipse mainly; so Solutions for eclipse would be most appreciated, but any IDE (or command line debugger) will do.
Thanks!

Comment: An IDE that continually compiles in the background when you execute (i.e. run, debug, deploy, etc) would be more advantageous.  I believe that Eclipse can be configured in this manner.

Comment: I do know about eclipse's "build automatically".  I'm unable to recompile and redeploy the jar files.  The jar file exists on a remote machine, and my local compile is a more recent version.

Comment: FWIW I have never seen the behavior you describe in Visual Studio.  Now, I only do C++ development in VS, so maybe the C# debugger has that capability - but if I set a breakpoint in VS C++ and the line numbers have changed since I compiled the EXE/DLL that I'm debugging, it absolutely does not just "figure it out".  In fact, we have a fairly strict source control policy that we capture the compiled PDB file along with the source for every commit so we can reconstruct problems.

Answer (score 4):

**When developing just use and link to `.class` files that are saved by your IDE.**

If your project starts to grow to a point where it's really useful to link to a `.jar` you're better off treating the jar's as separate projects.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work :(.   I know how to do all of these things in C++, so I figure there must be a way in JAVA!

Answer (score 4):

Go to Project tab in Eclipse and then

- click clean: Project->Clean…
- click build automatically: Project->Build automatically

Answer (score 3):

Use [method breakpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-set_method_breakpoints.htm) instead of line breakpoints. They can be set to halt on entering/exiting a method. You get them by double clicking the left editor side in a line containing a method declaration.

Comment: Although this really does look like it should work, I've tested this and it does NOT work when the code is out of sync from the jar file.

Comment: @Grothaar In my case, my code is out of sync from the jar because of losing comments inside the code. So the line number is completely un-sync. When using method breakpoint, although debug pointer is not shown, I can press F6 (on Eclipse) and imagine where the debug pointer is, and I am able to track the variables' value too.

Answer (score 1):

The debug information is limited to line numbers in the source file...  I do agree that having a warning that the lines are wrong would be nice, but that would require more meta data in the jar than I think is available...

You might want to consider addressing the challenge with a change in your build process.  This isn't exactly answering your question, but hopefully it will give you a strategy that will address the underlying problem.

When you generate the jar for deployment, also generate a jar with the binary AND source.  For investigating the source code of a stack trace on the live server, set up a separate project in eclipse and have the binary+source jar be on the classpath.  You may have to explicitly set the source code location back to the same jar (though I think Eclipse will just do this automatically).

Then you just have to add copying of the binary+source jar into the appropriate location in your workspace as you do your deployments (preferably with a deployment script).

If it's your server, you may want to even consider deploying the binary+source jar to the live server - that way you will always be able to get at the source.